# SSL Error - unable to read server certificate from file

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I've been setting up SSL for my domain today, and have struck another issue - I was hoping someone could shed some light on..

I keep receiving the following error messages:

```
[error] Init: Unable to read server certificate from file /etc/apache2/domain.com.ssl/domain.com.crt/domain.com.crt
[error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
```

I'm running Apache 2.2.16 and Ubuntu 10.10.  My .crt file has the Begin and End tags, and has been copied exactly from the confirmation email I received, very frustrating!

Cheers!

Edit >>
When trying to verify the .crt It doesn't seem to work:

```
>> openssl x509 -noout -text -in domain.com.crt 
unable to load certificate
16851:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:650:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Also >>

```
>> openssl x509 -text -inform PEM -in domain.com.crt
unable to load certificate
21321:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:650:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

```
>> openssl x509 -text -inform DER -in domain.com.crt
unable to load certificate
21325:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1316:
21325:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:380:Type=X509
```

Edit>>
(Cheers for the help by the way)

```
>> grep '^-----' domain.com.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Just emailed the company providing the Certificate, they responded>

> I have checked the CSR file that you have provided and I can assure
>   that this was correctly generated. The error that you are currently
>   encountering is caused because you are using a wrong command line for
>   installing the CSR. You will need to modify this domain.com.crt from
>   your command line with the according name of your domain.

- currently the crt is set up to mysite.com.crt - I've used domain.com.crt as an example

Comment: Could you please show us the output of `grep '^-----' domain.com.crt`?

Comment: Williamsowen, the whole point of a certificate is to be shown to anyone who connects to your webserver; it's not a private thing.  That given, would you consider attaching or posting the whole certificate here so we can look directly at it instead of having to guess?

Comment: Hang on, I see you've just accepted my answer.  Does that mean that it was terminal Windows linefeeds that were causing the problem?

Comment: MadHatter - apologies! New to this, but I've just got it working, the formatting from the email I receieved was off, couldn't thank you guys enough!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Is it possible that the lines are ^M-terminated?  This is a potential issue when moving files from Windows to UNIX systems.  One easy way to check is to use `vi` in "show me the binary" mode, with `vi -b /etc/apache2/domain.ssl/domain.ssl.crt/domain.com.crt`.

If each line ends with a control-M, like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----^M
MIIDITCCAoqgAwIBAgIQL9+89q6RUm0PmqPfQDQ+mjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBM^M
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJaQTElMCMGA1UEChMcVGhhd3RlIENvbnN1bHRpbmcgKFB0eSkg^M
THRkLjEWMBQGA1UEAxMNVGhhd3RlIFNHQyBDQTAeFw0wOTEyMTgwMDAwMDBaFw0x^M
```

you've got a file in Windows line-terminated format, and apache doesn't love those.

Your options include moving the file over again, taking more care; or using the `dos2unix` command to strip those out; you can also remove them inside vi, if you're careful.

---

**Edit**: thanks to @dave_thompson_085, who points out that this answer no longer applies in 2019.  That is, Apache/OpenSSL are now tolerant of ^M-terminated lines, so they don't cause problems.  That said, other formatting errors, several different examples of which appear in the comments, can still cause problems; check carefully for these if the certificate has been moved across systems.

Comment: For me it was a copy&paste error, omitting the first couple of characters of the header `-----BE`... Thanks for the inspiration to double check!

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem!

In notepad++ in windows you can use the EDIT-EOL conversion dialog to change set the correct LF format.

And you can use the View-Show Symbol menu to actually see the windows CR LF line endings.

Comment: My certificate simply ended up being an empty file. Something got broke in the generation I guess. This answer encouraged me to open it up and see that.

Comment: Note to Windows users: You'll probably need to convert the line format to UNIX even if you're on Windows. DOS2UNIX is not a Windows command, but a Linux one. The good news, Git for Windows provides it. CigWin probably does too, but not sure about it.

Comment: Note to Windows users: a list of permissions in Windows Explorer's Properties / Security tab gets messed up after copying a restricted-permissions file from a network share with Cygwin's cp.  E.g., I saw a "NUL SID", a disabled Everyone and domain users entries.

Comment: Also, it needs literal new line characters. I ran into a problem where the cert I was given had `\n` instead of true new lines. `sed 's/\\n/\
'/g` did the trick. (That blank is supposed to be a new line)

Comment: **CRLF shouldn't matter**; Apache uses OpenSSL and OpenSSL accepts and ignores CR in PEM on all systems even Unix. However, there is a different Windows-caused issue: many Windows programs like to put a Byte Order Mark, appropriately abbreviated BOM(b!), at the beginning of the file and thus the beginning of the first line, which OpenSSL does NOT accept. `vi -b`, or `cat -v`, should show this; I don't _think_ `dos2unix` fixes it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you for that, I just checked and you're right.  Given what I wrote, and the upvotes and comments, I can only surmise that what I wrote *was* true seven and a half years ago, when I wrote it, and Apache/OpenSSL have improved in the interim.  I shall amend the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is not recent. I can't explain what others experienced or did, but I have successfully used PEM-with-CRLF everywhere since at least 2005, including Unix systems that no longer exist like SunOS and AIX 4. I noticed this early on because in the same timeframe I was also sharing/moving between Windows and Unix other files that _did_ need EOL conversion.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 fair enough, but others have reported otherwise in comments above, so I don't intend to further modify this answer.

Answer (score 29):

For anyone arriving at this page with a similar error when trying to read a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) (note that OP is reading a certificate): make sure to use the right OpenSSL command. `x509` is for certificates and `req` is for CSRs:

```
openssl req -in server.csr -text -noout
```

vs

```
openssl x509 -in server.crt -text -noout
```

Answer (score 26):

```
>> openssl x509 -noout -text -in domain.com.crt 
unable to load certificate
16851:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:650:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

I suspect that you have a problem with the format of the certificate.

Run both of two following commands and give us the output:

```
openssl x509 -text -inform DER -in domain.com.crt 
openssl x509 -text -inform PEM -in domain.com.crt
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was able to determine the format my SAs provided as ".cer" were already ".pem" _incognito_

Comment: This was helpful !!! actually a generated cer file in windows was actually a pem

Answer (score 20):

Just went round and round in circles on this, and it turned out I had the certificates around the wrong way - e.g.

```
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
```

instead of:

```
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
```

Something to check if you're getting this error.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I found my certificate had different "-" characters. Must have been a copy/paste issue from the admin that placed the cert onto the server, with the text editor replacing -- with a special unicode character along the way.

This took hours to diagnose, and in the end I just guessed at it, and edited the cert in vi and deleted the existing "-" characters, and retyped them.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: slack did this to me! thanks

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I encountered the OP's errors because whoever created the .crt file for me in the first place had really created a **.PEM** formatted file, and named it .crt.

I discovered this by running into the following helpful guide:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200103195255/https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them.

EDIT NOTE: The originally posted URL is no longer working but included for completeness:
https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them

all I had to do was rename my .crt to a .pem, and I was done! The guide indicated that the errors from the OP's question imply that the input file is PEM formatted already, so attempting to convert it to .pem from a DER format cannot be done, and is in fact unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your file has no trailing or leading spaces within the certificate file. Carefully ensure there are no spaces or blanks within your certificate file, by selecting the entire text and looking for blank spaces on a text only editor.

Also check if indeed all the configured files exist and are correct.

Eg: on your other post you say that your .key file is named **my**domain.com.crt while on the vhost configuration you have domain.com.crt

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/domain.ssl/domain.ssl.crt/domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/domain.ssl/domain.ssl.key/domain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/domain.ssl/ca.crt
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/domain.ssl/gs_intermediate_ca.crt
```

Check again that all the above files really exist and are valid.

Comment: Also check that your dashes are dashes.  Microsoftian text editors like to change `--` into `–`; that was not a lot of fun to troubleshoot.

Comment: yeap, since you're on Ubuntu, just open up a terminal and use nano for example. This way you'll be sure.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feed back - I've checked everything and all is good.  I've tried to verify the crt file however I get:
`sudo openssl x509 -noout -text -in domain.com.crt
unable to load certificate
16851:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:650:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`

Comment: Does the first line of your domain.com.crt file begin with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and the last line ends with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`?

Answer (score 1):

Should someone else run into this problem and your apache error logs say something like:

*Init: Unable to read server certificate from file /etc/apache2/domain.com.ssl/domain.com.crt/domain.com.crt*

Make sure you haven't swapped your key and certificate files in the declarations in the apache config.  I had pointed the key to my certificate file and the certificate to my key file.  This post helped me figure out the problem but I wanted to point it out as another potential problem/solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it has to do with BOM being present in the file. One could strip it like so:

```
tail -c +4 ssl.crt > ssl2.crt
```

Not sure if it always takes 3 bytes, so the better way must be:

```
vi -c 'se nobomb' -c wq ssl.crt
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I was sent the content of an IIS-style .p7b file pasted into an email.  It has "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" tags, just like .pem, and the content uses a similar looking base64 encoding.  I converted it to a *.pem file like so:

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in cert.p7b -out cert.cer
```

After that, Apache 2.2 was happy.

Answer (score 0):

My problem (having the same error while installing a new server with Apache 2.4) was that Apache (2.4) couldn't read the binary .crt file. I imported it in my personal certificate store  (with mmc) and exported it as base-64 encoded X.509 (.cer). Renamed the exported file to the same name (.crt) (used in my httpd-ssl.conf) and it worked again! 
The same certificate worked on my old server, maybe Apache 2.4 is more stringent then 2.2?
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error because **I switched .key with .crt** filenames

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I accidentally used a customer-supplied p7b type IIS cert in the apache config. Converting the cert to x509 format fixed the error. Both types look the same on the surface but are apparently different on the inside.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue using Lets Encrypt (letsencrypt) on Windows.  The cert came back encoded as UTF-16LE. Converting it to UTF-8 (using dos2unix) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was just the empty lines. When i pasted the crt file from ntepad or notepad ++ in nano always got smth like

```
sdgrgrgr rgregegreg rgrgreg
rgregreg rggregregr rgregrg
```

removing the empty spaces and putig all in a line solved the problem 
Eg :

```
sdgrgrgr
rgregegreg
rgrgreg
rgregreg
rggregregr
rgregrg
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the PEM file contained just the *key*, not the *certificate*.

Check the file contents, it must contain the line

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```