# SSL: couldn't read X509 certificate from pem file lighttpd

Tags: ssl-certificate, lighttpd

I have installed ssl key in the past on my lighttpd and I've documented the steps I did to make sure that I can replicate it in the future.  Well, I haven't touched the server for a while and I need to create a new web server with lighttpd that will support ssl.  Follow all my steps in my note and it gave me this error

```
SSL: couldn't read X509 certificate from PEM file
```

I'm not sure what I missed in my steps but if someone could please take a look at my steps and perhaps suggest what I missed, I'd really appreciate it.

This is my environment

```
CentOS 6.4 64 bit
lighttpd/1.4.35 (ssl) - a light and fast webserver
```

My ssl certificate is from startcom company

Here are my steps

Generate my csr

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out myserver.csr -keyout myserver_privatekey.key -subj "/C=us/ST=State/L=City/O=MyCompany/OU=Productions/CN=myserver.mycompany.net"
```

Send the csr to Startcom and get this ssl save it as

```
myserver.crt
```

Create the final PEM file

```
cat myserver_privatekey.key myserver.crt > myserver.pem
```

Got these 2 files from startcom

```
ca.pem 
sub.class1.server.ca.pem
```

Unified those 2 files

```
cat ca.pem sub.class1.server.ca.pem >> ca-certs.crt
```

Move the crt and pem file to myssl directory

Here is my lighttpd configuration:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "0.0.0.0:443" {
        ssl.engine  = "enable"
        ssl.ca-file = "/etc/lighttpd/myssl/ca-certs.crt"
        ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/myssl/myserver.pem"

}

$SERVER["socket"] == "[::]:443" {
        ssl.engine  = "enable"
        ssl.ca-file = "/etc/lighttpd/myssl/ca-certs.crt"
        ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/myssl/myserver.pem"

}

$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(myserver\.)?mycompany\.net$" {
        ssl.ca-file = "/etc/lighttpd/myssl/ca-certs.crt"
        ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/myssl/myserver.pem"
    server.document-root = "/var/www/lighttpd/mywebsite"

}
```

So when I'm done, I restarted my lighttpd and this is the error I got.

```
Starting lighttpd: 2015-09-20 15:58:32: (network.c.543) SSL: couldn't read X509 certificate from '/etc/lighttpd/myssl/myserver.pem'
```

I've either never or haven't seen that error in the past so I'm not quite sure how to move forward from there.  Can anyone give me your 2 cents on what I missed?  Please help?

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue?

Comment: shouldn't be.  Because it has the same ownership like the lighttpd.  But just for the heck of it, I tried to change it to the apps ownership and the error is still the same.

Comment: What does `openssl x509 -noout -text -inform PEM -in /etc/lighttpd/myssl/myserver.pem` show?  If that doesn't work, try changing `-inform PEM` to `-inform DER`.

Comment: This post (http://serverfault.com/questions/316907/ssl-error-unable-to-read-server-certificate-from-file) talks about another possible culprit that affects apache, and might happen for `nginx` as well.

Answer (score 2):

For me, putting a new line in between the key and crt in the PEM file solved this.

```
cat my_server.key <(echo) my_server.crt > my_server.pem
```